# Dynamically creating the name of an existing object to Set one of its properties

Tags: powershell

I have the following code in Powershell:

```
function New-Row-Object-Instance {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Zeros = 0
        Tens = 0
        Twentys = 0
        Thirtys = 0
        Fortys = 0
        Fiftys = 0
        Sixtys = 0
    }
    $Row_Details = New-Row-Object-Instance
```

I Updated `$Row_Details` with some values. Now I have the following Labels on a Windows Form that is displayed: `$Zeros`, `$Tens`, `$Twentys`, `$Thirtys` etc.

I want to update the Labels on Form with values using the property Content.
So $Zeros.Content = 2 and so forth

```
foreach ($property in $Row_Details.PSObject.Properties) {
    $property.Name >> $OutFile
# following creates the label names $Zeros,....
    $v = -join('$',$property.Name)
# following gives error.. no property named Content
    $v.Content = 2
# following gives error.. no property named Content
    (-join('$',$property.Name)).Content = 2
# following gives error.. no property named Content
    $v | Set-ItemProperty -Name "Content" -Value 2
# following does not update the Labels on the Form itself
    Set-Variable $v -Value @{Content = "2"}

# Cannot use Set-ItemProperty -inputObject $v because cannot name property
}
```

I can hard code name of each Label, but was trying to do it dynamically or Elegantly...

Comment: So there is a variable called `$zeros` which has a `content` property. That property you want to populate with corresponding property in `$row_details` etc.? Correct

Comment: Thank you, Matt... yes, exactly.. Already have variables $zeros, etc on a windows form.... I want to populate with values taken from $row_details...

Comment: Let me claify... $Zeros, Tens, $Twentys, $Thirtys etc.. are Separate and are Labels on a Windows form like Textboxes, etc. So I update what they display using $Zeros.Content = 5 ... and so forth. I matched their names to the properties of $Row_Details... I want to dynamically refer their names in a loop to update each by using the names to the properties of $Row_Details and tacking a $ in front...

Comment: Yes. That is how I understood it. The only issue you could be having is a potential scope one since we do not know where they are actually defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I really understand your question, but I'll give it a try with a small example that might put you on a track to follow:

```
$object =  New-Object PSObject -Property @{   
    Zeros = 0;
    Tens = 0;
}

$Zeros = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Content = "0"
}

$Tens = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Content = "0"
}

$Zeros
$Tens

$object.PSObject.Properties | %{

    $property = $_.Name
    $expression = "`$$($property).Content = `"2`""

    Invoke-Expression $expression
}

$Zeros
$Tens
```

Comment: Thank you, David. Invoke-Expression $expression worked.         
foreach ($property in $Row_Details.PSObject.Properties) {
        $freq = 2
        $v = -join('$',$property.Name)
        $expression = "$v.Content = $freq"
        Invoke-Expression $expression
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear to me, but maybe this helps

If you just want to modify the values for each of them you an do this:

```
foreach ($property in $Row_Details.PSObject.Properties)
{
    $property.Value = 0
}
```

If you want to make new variables for each item:

```
foreach ($property in $Row_Details.PSObject.Properties)
{
    New-Variable -Name $property.Name -Value $property.Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Get-Variable for this is interact with those other objects. Shrinking your examples down to two you can proof of concept this fairly easily.

```
# Simulate your controls by creating object with those respective properties
$Zeros = New-Object PSObject -Property @{Content = 0}
$Tens = New-Object PSObject -Property @{Content = 0}

$Row_Details = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Zeros = 1
    Tens = 2
}

# Display the current Contents
write-host "Zeros: $($Zeros.Content)"
write-host "Tens: $($Tens.Content)"

foreach ($property in $Row_Details.PSObject.Properties){
    $singleVariable = Get-Variable $property.name
    $singleVariable.Value.content = $property.Value
}

# Show the updated Contents
write-host "Zeros: $($Zeros.Content)"
write-host "Tens: $($Tens.Content)"
```

The results of this being

```
Zeros: 0
Tens: 0
Zeros: 1
Tens: 2
```

The only problem I see is that all of this exists in the same scope so you my example should work as intended. However, depending where your variables are defined, you might have scope issues. If that happens you just need to experiment with the `-Scope` parameter of `Get-Variable`